# Problem with Nginx: Page shows IP address instead of server name

Tags: nginx

I have installed Nginx on an Ubuntu Server 18.04 and trying to make it work with Odoo.

The steps:

- Registered an A record for my desired "subdomain" that points to my server;

(Tested mysubdomain.com on browser and it correctly redirects to my server - I can see server IP address and default nginx welcome page)

- Setup my "default site" using the following setup:

  ```
  server {

      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;

      root /var/www/html;

      #Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name mysubdomain.mydomain.com;

      location / {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:8069;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Conection 'upgrade';
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
  }
  ```

After restarting Nginx service and entetinr the "mysubdomain.mydomain.com" on browser, everything is running fine, but browser shows my IP instead of keeping "mysubdomain" on the web address.

What can be wrong?

**EDITED ON 5TH JANUARY 2020**

I have re-created my VPN and changed the A record for my subdomain to the new IP and reinstalled Nginx.

Everything worked as expected this time and I believe the problem was related to the domain name hosting service. Perhaps I had to wait a while to allow subdomain name to propagate or something else.

Comment: It might just be your terminology, but what do you mean, **exactly**, by `it correctly redirects to my server`?  Setting up an A record does not involve any redirects.  Check your browser's devtools network tab - do you see a single 200 GET request, or are you really seeing that followed by a second GET with 301 status or similar redirect? If you are, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when your Host header is missing while proxy passing. Can you add `proxy_add_header Host "mysubdomain.mydomain.com"` ?

Also, as a good hygiene practice, proxy_pass directive should be used after proxy_set_headers.

Comment: Anand, thank you. I have updated my question.Anyway I have "saved" your answer for reference.